# How do I invoke Objective-C methods on SWT objects?

Tags: java, objective-c, swt

I'd like to use a Java application to display text in the system tray / task bar on OS X in a native way. I'd like to do this by invoking `setTitle` on the `NSStatusItem` (like in [this example](http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/01/creating-a-status-bar-application/)). I've never accessed the underlying native libraries in SWT, and I'm having trouble with it.

Someone on [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/928169/) demonstrated how to invoke an Objective-C method to change a property of a window in SWT (the full-screen button). Here is his/her code:

```
Field field = Control.class.getDeclaredField("view");
Object /*NSView*/ view = field.get(rShell);

if (view != null)
{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView");
    Object /*NSWindow*/ window = c.getDeclaredMethod("window").invoke(view);

    c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow");
    Method setCollectionBehavior = c.getDeclaredMethod(
        "setCollectionBehavior", JVM.is64bit() ? long.class : int.class);
    setCollectionBehavior.invoke(window, getFullScreenMask());
}
```

So I suppose this would result in this Objective-C code:

```
[window setCollectionBehaviour:1<<7];
```

Now I'd like to do the same for an SWT `TrayItem`. The goal is to get the equivalent of this Objective-C code:

```
[statusItem setTitle:@"Status"];
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView field org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.view to org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrayItem
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:18)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:358)
    at com.teez.status.MainStatus.main(MainStatus.java:35)
```

I'm not sure what this means. I marked the line where the exception is thrown. What other issues could I run into while attempting this? Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tray;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TrayItem;

public class MainStatus {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        Tray tray = display.getSystemTray();


        if (tray != null) {
            TrayItem item = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);

            Field field = Control.class.getDeclaredField("view");
            Object /*NSView*/ view = field.get(item); //Exception thrown here

            if (view != null)
            {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSView");
                Object /*NSWindow*/ window = c.getDeclaredMethod("window").invoke(view);

                c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSStatusItem");


                Method setCollectionBehavior = c.getDeclaredMethod("setTitle", long.class);

                setCollectionBehavior.invoke(window, "Desired title");
            }

            while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
            }
            display.dispose ();

        }

    }

}
```

Edit: Thanks Eugene for solving this problem, but the text is still not showing up on the status bar, so I asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080795/cant-set-title-of-nsstatusitem-from-swt-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tray item is not a control. You need to look for a Cocoa handle in that class hierarchy.

Judging from [sources](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/cocoa/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/TrayItem.java) the Cocoa handle is stored in "item" field and it is instance of NSStatusItem.

Unfortunately, I can't test it atm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how to try this. Should I change the "view" to something else?

Comment: You need to change "Control.class.getDeclaredField("view");" to something like "TrayItem.class.getDeclaredField("item");" I'm on Linux atm and can't test it.

Comment: Note that this is regular Java reflection API, it's not SWT (or Cocoa) specific - it's simply a way to "peek inside."

Comment: Okay I tried it. I edited my question to show the exception that was thrown. Sorry, I don't understand reflection, so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Okay, the exception was caused because I needed to do a `field.setAccessible(true);`. Now it's saying that there's no method `setTitle(java.lang.String)` in `NSStatusItem`. Do you have any idea how to send a message to an Objective-C object?